# 2 dataframes con mismas filas y columnas, quiero reemplazar ciertos datos de una en otra

Tags: pandas

En la empresa tenemos una tabla donde las columnas son ID de empresas y las filas son nombres de epígrafes contables, que contienen cifras de cada una.

El problema es que para determinadas empresas, a lo mejor no queremos que en una fila aparezca ninguna cifra, y queremos que aparezca una **"x"** para indicar que hemos decidido personalmente no incluir esa cifra de epígrafe para esa compañía.

Dispongo de dos ficheros:

1. Fichero completo (todas las cifras de todos los epígrafes de cada compañía).
2. Mismo fichero en estructura pero sin ninguna cifra y únicamente valores (**"x"**) en las celdas que quiero reemplazar la cifra del fichero 1 con una **"x"**.

Lo primero que se me había ocurrido era utilizar algún Merge, pero no me ha dado el resultado esperado...

Como no sé si me he explicado bien, dejo una imagen con un ejemplo de los ficheros que tengo (el fichero 1 es el de arriba, el 2 el de abajo y la tercera tala es lo que quiero como resultado).
Os dejo también las tablas escritas para hacerlo más fácil. Están en el orden explicado anteriormente.

|  | EMPRESA 1 | EMPRESA 2 | EMPRESA 3 | EMPRESA 4 | EMPRESA 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEUDAS L/P | 2910 | 4224 | 6302 | 8086 | 7999 |
| CLIENTES | 1914 | 8643 | 3960 | 9525 | 8477 |
| VENTAS | 7691 | 7156 | 9972 | 1910 | 2562 |
| IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS | 7943 | 5720 | 2192 | 3715 | 9240 |

|  | EMPRESA 1 | EMPRESA 2 | EMPRESA 3 | EMPRESA 4 | EMPRESA 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEUDAS L/P | x |  | x |  | x |
| CLIENTES |  | x |  |  |  |
| VENTAS |  |  |  | x |  |
| IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS |  |  |  |  | x |

|  | EMPRESA 1 | EMPRESA 2 | EMPRESA 3 | EMPRESA 4 | EMPRESA 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEUDAS L/P | x | 4224 | x | 8086 | x |
| CLIENTES | 1914 | x | 3960 | 9525 | 8477 |
| VENTAS | 7691 | 7156 | 9972 | x | 2562 |
| IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS | 7943 | 5720 | 2192 | 3715 | x |

Como soy nobato en esto, lo que he intentado me ha dado errores por todos lados... Intenté hacer algún if y replace, pero no supe como hacerlo. Lo único que me salió (aunque no sirviera) fue un merge... Pero no conseguí lo que buscaba.
Les agradecería mucho su ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los datos pegados en forma de imagen no ayudan a que consigas respuestas, pues obligaría a quien te ayude a copiar a mano los números. ¿Puedes poner esos mismos ejemplos como texto? Por otro lado también ayudará que pongas el código que has intentado, aunque no haya funcionado.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón abulafia. Lo he modificado para facilitaros el tratamiento. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más directa y sencilla es utilizar [pandas.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). Esta función te permite aplicar a cada celda de un dataframe una condición (que puede estar basada en otro dataframe) y si la condición se cumple, deja pasar tal cual el dato que había y si no se cumple se reemplaza por otro que tú le digas.

Así pues, si `df1` y `df2` son los dataframes que has dado en el enunciado:

```html
>>> print(df1)
                   EMPRESA 1 EMPRESA 2 EMPRESA 3 EMPRESA 4 EMPRESA 5
DEUDAS L/P               2910      4224      6302      8086      7999
CLIENTES                 1914      8643      3960      9525      8477
VENTAS                   7691      7156      9972      1910      2562
IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS      7943      5720      2192      3715      9240

>>> print(df2)
                    EMPRESA 1 EMPRESA 2 EMPRESA 3 EMPRESA 4 EMPRESA 5
DEUDAS L/P                  x                   x                   x
CLIENTES                              x                              
VENTAS                                                    x          
IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS                                                 x
```

haríamos lo siguiente:

```py
df3 = df1.where(df2!="x", other="x")
```

Como ves la condición es que `df2` contenga algo diferente de "x". Si se cumple, se tomará el valor que hubiera en `df1` (porque el `.where()` lo estamos aplicando sobre `df1`). Si no se cumple se usará el parámetro `other` y se asignará una "x".

El resultado:

```html
>>> print(df3)
                    EMPRESA 1 EMPRESA 2 EMPRESA 3 EMPRESA 4 EMPRESA 5
DEUDAS L/P                  x      4224         x      8086         x
CLIENTES                 1914         x      3960      9525      8477
VENTAS                   7691      7156      9972         x      2562
IMPUESTOS DIFERIDOS      7943      5720      2192      3715         x
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta abulafia!!! me has solucionado el problema!